# Latex outputs "?figurename?" surrounded by question marks in output file

Tags: formatting, latex, pdflatex, lyx

Good day, I've been having a lot of trouble getting Latex to output a normal figurename. For some reason, each caption reads "?figurename? x" (with x being the number of the image), despite me not specifying any \figurename. I've tried changing stuff around but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\proofname}{proof}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm,headheight=2cm,headsep=0.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\begin{filecontents*}{example.eps}
gsave
newpath
  20 20 moveto
  20 220 lineto
  220 220 lineto
  220 20 lineto
closepath
2 setlinewidth
gsave
  .4 setgray fill
grestore
stroke
grestore
\end{filecontents*}
%
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
%
\begin{document}
\title{some title}
\subtitle{some subtitle}
\author{Me}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro1}
\input{input_containing_pictures.tex}
\begin{figure}
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{img/resnetplot}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{Precision-Recall\label{fig:Curves-1}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Of course I don't have access to your files and have to remove `\input{input_containing_pictures.tex}` etc, but then your code works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkFar.png

Comment: Nevermind, friend, I found out what was wrong with it, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I managed to find the error: somewhere in my inputs a bunch of rogue `\selectlanguage{english}` kept changing the default language for the article. The language options couldn't decide which \figurename was the correct one so it kept throwing me a ?figurename?.